# What's the header file for BasicHttpRequest

Tags: java, apache, http, components

What's the header file for BasicHttpRequest? I am using Apache HttpComponents.

I'm trying to make a simple program, but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory 
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.(AbstractHttpClient.java:159)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.(DefaultHttpClient.java:178) at test.main(test.java:24) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
```

What is the header file for this line:

```
HttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", "/",HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but i am getting error."?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:159)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:178)
 at test.main(test.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)

Comment: I'm debating rewording this to say "What's are required `import` s for `BasicHttpRequest`?" or alternatively "What dependencies must I include, and what must I import for `BasicHttpRequest`?", but my belief is that the OP may not get the level of desired support by making such an edit..

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have "header files" like you have in C or C++. The error that you get is a runtime error (not a compile-time error), it doesn't have anything to do with a missing "header file".

Looking at the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory ...

It complains that it cannot find the class `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`. The Apache HttpComponents library has a number of dependencies; one of them is [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/). You need to download that library and put the JAR file in your classpath.

Besides Commons Logging there are other dependencies. You have to make sure you have them all in your classpath. See this page: [Dependencies for Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/quickstart.html)